# no image being displayed in a php programme

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

can anybody explain to me why every other page manages to display my images as required, but this page does not. Its apart of a login form by clever techy off youtube. Iv been trying to style it myself, but not knowling much about php im trying to work around it, But iv managed to get it doing as i want other than when i land on this sucsess page after login i get no image displayed and the form is left top instead of centred. i dont get it.. here is the sucess page code....

```
<?php
/* Displays all successful messages */
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Success</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>


<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.gif', 'bg-02.gif', 'bg-03.gif', 'bg-04.gif', 'bg-05.gif', 'bg-06.gif', 'bg-07.gif' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

<style>

  #wrapper{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:10px;

       background: url("signinimages/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
  }

  .fader{
      opacity:0;
      transition:4s;
  }

  .faderin{
      opacity:1;
      transition:4s;
  }
</style>

<script>
window.onload=(function(){
document.getElementById('wrapper').classList.remove("fader");
document.getElementById('wrapper').classList.add("faderin");
});

</script>

<body>

<div id='wrapper' class='fader'>

<div class="form">
    <h1><?= 'Success'; ?></h1>
    <p>
    <?php 
    if( isset($_SESSION['message']) AND !empty($_SESSION['message']) ):
        echo $_SESSION['message'];    
    else:
        header( "location: index.php" );
    endif;
    ?>
    </p>
    <a href="index.php"><button class="button button-block"/>back to Sign in</button></a>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the video with the full code..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pz5CbLqdGwM

And here is the full code in file.

https://clevertechie.com/files/login-...

And here is a text version to read if you wish.

https://clevertechie.com/php/20/login-system-php-mysql-database

I dont know what im doing wrong... thanks for any help if anybody can see what this is doing and why its not doing what i wish..

Comment: Change `$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"` to `$selectedBg = $bg[$i]`

Comment: The code works fine, but if the "message" session variable does not exist or is null the page will be redirected to index.php automatically.

Comment: its not the code thats the problem, the problem is, success.php will not allow it to be displayed. i have no idea why not, the same code runs on all otther pages bar success.php , reset.php and error.php.. message veriable is present and displayed. everything is sound. other than it just will not let me display the images????

Comment: It has something to do with the css being re-introduced. everytime the page success shows, the old css is current, instead of my adaptations... Iv cleared cache ect and disabled it, but the bloody css still keeps reloading out of nowhere. its really wierd.